# Java ResourceBundle .properties

Tags: java, resourcebundle

Возникла такая проблема: хочу организовать мультиязычность, для этого в создал несколько `.properties` файлов.

При использовании ResourceBundle вылетает с ошибкой

> MissingResourceException

Вызывается все в классе `ClientProductHelper`. Файлы ресурсов названы соответственно `ClientProductHelper_en` и `ClientProductHelper_ru`. Пробовал менять конец названия на `_EN/_RU` и `_en_EN/_ru_RU` - одна и та же ошибка.

```
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ClientProductHelper");
```

Locale опознает корректно по дефолту, а файл с ресурсами найти не может.

Где я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался. Достаточно было просто указать полный путь до файлов

```
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ru.....helper.ClientProductHelper", Locale.getDefault());
```